# Why should we say 応えられなくなってきて and not 応えられなくてきて?

Tags: grammar

Why should we say 応えられなく_**なって**_きて and not 応えられなくて_きて?
I have been told that 応えられなくてきて is not correct by a japanese friend of mine but the explications were... light.

Thank you

Comment: While there is a [応]{こた}える, you probably mean [答]{こた}える which is much more common.... (the meanings are non-identical).

Comment: 応える means "repay" and 答える means "answer".

Comment: Sorry, i didn't post the original sentence.

彼女の気持ちに**応えられなくなってきて**、別れたほうがいいと思いました。

Is the kanji right?

Comment: Yes, it is right.

Comment: @SmallPox What would you imagine 応えられなくてきて should mean, I wonder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly where your doubt lies, but:

1. 応えられなくてきて
   *(I) come without being able to live up to it, so...*
2. 応えられないできて
   *(I) have never been able to live up to it so far, so...*
3. 応えられなくなってきて
   *(I) become less and less able to live up to it, so...*

Among them I think only #3 is suitable for your sentence.

> 彼女の気持ちに**応えられなくなってきて**、別れたほうがいいと思いました。

Comment: 「live up to 人's expectation/ideal/standard」 とかだと「人の期待に応える」とかの意味になるけど、「live up to 人」だと「～にかなう」とか「その人に匹敵するくらい立派になる」とかになると思いますので 「live up to (her」の後に何か入れたほうがいいかも・・・

Comment: @choco ありがとうございます>< Live up to choco-san できるよう努力します…

Answer (score 2):

Because なってくる is one phrase.

応えない(I don't repay),
応えられない(I can't repay),
応えられなくなる,
応えられなくなってくる.

応えなくて、応えられなくて、応えられなくなって、応えられなくなってきて.

I don't know the translation of last two phrase in English.

Comment: 応えられなくなる "I become unable to repay", 応えられなくなってくる "I am becoming unable to repay / I am becoming less able to repay", ・・・とかでどうでしょうか・・・(まわりくどいけど)

Comment: I think they are good translations but I am not English native speaker. I want to ask if these translations are natural for them.

Answer (score 1):

応えられなくてきて means "I came here because I couldn't reply, and...".
応えられなくなってきて means "I have (gradually) become unable to reply, and...".

Since 応えられない is an adjective (a verb conjugated to an adjective), which stands for a static state unlike verbs, which can stand for changes, combination with …てくる can't express gradual changes or accumulation.